# String Match How to implement

Tags: java, string

I have a class Matcher() as follows. find method accepts two strings: pattern (string to be looked for) and source (string where to look for). Example if pattern = "abc" and source = "abc cda abc" is passed to find method. It returns [0 4], i.e. the pattern abc(exact match) is found at index 0 and index 4 of source. Whatever you pass to pattern, it will consider that string as one pattern. Without modifying the following Matcher class, if I want to search for more than one pattern. What is the best way to do it? For example I want to call the find method from other class and if i have two patterns stored in arraylist then i want to pass one pattern first and return the result and again pass the 2nd pattern and return the result in one time. I want to stop processing only after both the patterns or the patterns in arraylist are looked for in source. Need your idea.

```
public class Matcher {

    public static List<Integer> find(String pattern, String source) {
        char[] x = pattern.toCharArray(), y = source.toCharArray();
        int i, j, m = x.length, n = y.length;
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        /* Searching */
        for (j = 0; j <= n - m; ++j) {
            for (i = 0; i < m && x[i] == y[i + j]; ++i)
                ;
            if (i >= m)
                result.add(j);
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: I put index 4. It should be 0 and 8. Example if pattern = "abc" and source = "abc cda abc" is passed to find method. It returns [0 8], i.e. the pattern abc(exact match) is found at index 0 and index 8 of source

Answer (score 0):

So, you want your method `find` to return a list of indexes? Did you have a look at [String.indexOf](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)? That might do exactly what you want.

Comment: The find method already returns list of indexes. But find method works only for one pattern. My arraylist has 3 patterns. I want to execute find method for all three patterns. for first pattern find method is called and returns index. then I want to do the same for 2nd pattern and return index and so on.

Comment: OK, assuming your patterns are in `List<String> myPatterns` and your source is in `source`, why don't you:   `for (String pattern : myPatterns) { List<Integer> results = Matcher.parse(pattern, source); /*handle results */ }`

Comment: for (String pattern : Read.arrayList) { List<Integer> results = Matcher.find(pattern, source); System.out.println(results); }   
I used the above loop, and now its working and printing index. But I don want to print the index , I want to print the matched pattern(string). what should I add to the code to print the matched string only. Thank you for your help

Comment: Well you know the matched pattern; it is `pattern`. So, after getting `results` you could add; `if (!results.isEmpty()) { System.out.println(pattern); }`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you answered your own question. You'll need to use a loop in your client code to make repeated calls to the find() method.  You won't be able to do it in a single call unless you rewrite your find method, which you don't want to do.  Your client code in mangled pseudocode:

```
declare a Matcher object
for (each pattern I want to match)
  call the find method with the pattern and the source string
  store the result
end loop
```

How you deal with the result will depend on what you need to do with it. You could create an ArrayList object and append the List objects to it.  Or you could create a HashMap and use the pattern as a key to the List objects if you need to know which pattern is where.

Let me know if I completely missed your point.

Cheers, 
dean

Comment: for (String pattern : Read.arrayList) {
List<Integer> results = Matcher.find(pattern, source);  
System.out.println(results);
   }

Comment: I used the above loop, and now its working and printing index. But I don want to print the index , I want to print the matched pattern(string). what should I add to the code to print the matched string only.

Comment: Your use of `System.out.println(results)` is just going to print the contents of your array using the default `toString` method defined in `ArrayList`.  You will need to print the pattern separately from the results, and you will need to write a nested loop to print the results.  For example:  for (Integer result : results) { System.out.println(result); }  with formatting to suit your display need.